# Linux Mint installation help

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

Installing LM through dual-booting on W10. I just put the .iso file on my DVD, when I try to mount it says 'Not possible mounting files of a virtual hard drive from image files or from a portable medium which isn't formatted using NTFS file system.

Comment: You do not mount the ISO from Windows. You have to use an installer to convert ISO to a bootable device and reboot into it. Most systems with UEFI secure boot off will offer both BIOS & UEFI boot, but if Windows is UEFI, you must boot installer in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: The https://rufus.ie open source app is recommended to make Linux LiveUSBs. See https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1795336#p1795336

Comment: Thank you, now I'm installing.